# Accessing methods from a variable type class

Tags: java, android, class, physics-engine

So I'm working on creating my own physics engine for an app that I'm creating.  At the moment I've got a `StaticObject` class for simple objects that don't simulate every game tick, and a `DynamicObject` class for objects that pertain to gravity and collisions and such.  Next, I'm creating a constraint class to create links between these different objects, like making this `dynamicObject` stay at the same position as this `staticObject`.

Alright, I'm trying to access some methods and values in the Object Classes(`StaticObject` or `DynamicObject`) from the `Constraint` class, but the specific type/class that I am accessing is variable.  It could be either of type `StaticObject`, or `DynamicObject`.

This is the class that needs access to the `Object` classes, or 'variable type class'(I don't know the proper terms here, I would like to know though, a bit new to this aspect of java):

```
public class Constraint<objectType1, objectType2> {

    private Class<objectType1> object1;
    private Class<objectType2> object2;


    public Constraint(Class<objectType1> object1, Class<objectType2> object2) {

        this.object1 = object1;
        this.object2 = object2;
    }

    public void update() {

        object2.position = object1.position;
    }

}
```

I know for certain that whatever type the Objects are( `StaticObject` or `DynamicObject ), they will each have the attribute`object.position`.

So, my question comes down to: How do I determine that the variable classes are of the correct types(`StaticObject`, or `DynamicObject`) and then how do I access methods and variables within the classes regardless of the type?  Am I headed in the right direction?  If not, what better ways can I learn?

Examples please, this is new to me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a mix of [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) and some [Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

The `SuperClass` here serves as the class that can have the common properties from the `StaticObject` and the `DynamicObject`.

The generic class `Constraint` can then accept any type which extends this `SuperClass`

Apart from this you can use the `instaceof` operator to check whether the type is `StaticObject` or the `DynamicObject` before performing any operation specific to one of these two classes.

I hope this example can lead you to exactly what your trying to implement.

```
class SuperClass{
    private int position;

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
}

class StaticObject extends SuperClass{

    StaticObject(int position){
        setPosition(position);
    }

}

class DynamicObject extends SuperClass{

    DynamicObject(int position){
        setPosition(position);
    }
}

public class Constraint<T1 extends SuperClass, T2 extends SuperClass> {

    private T1 object1;
    private T2 object2;


    public Constraint(T1 object1, T2 object2) {

        this.object1 = object1;
        this.object2 = object2;
    }

    public void update() {

        object2.setPosition(object1.getPosition());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Constraint<StaticObject, DynamicObject> c = new Constraint<StaticObject, DynamicObject>(new StaticObject(2), new DynamicObject(5));
        c.update();
    }

}
```

Comment: So, generics is the variable type stuff?

Comment: Yes in some ways it is. Read more about how generics is used in Java Collections.